# KolmogorovSmirnovTest memory issue

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, memory

I have a strange issue where the following program eats all memory. By commenting/uncommentig I found that the problem is connected to the KolmogorovSmirnovTest command.
The txt files are just files with numbers. **i** is the Length of list (**dis**) which we get from the file. Files with the same **i** have the same size. All files combined are ~30GB if you really need it I can try to upload it.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
ic = 50;
i = Table[2500*j, {j, ic}];
n = {200};
r = 1000;
KSTL = Table[0, {j, ic}];
Do[
 Print["i=" <> ToString[i[[j]]] <> " r=" <> ToString[k] <> 
   " Memory= " <> ToString[MemoryInUse[]]];

 str = OpenRead[
   "/home/someone/somewhere/results_r1000/fi_\
i_" <> ToString[i[[j]]] <> "_n_" <> ToString[n[[1]]] <> "_r_" <> 
    ToString[k - 1] <> ".txt"];
 dis = ReadList[str, Number];
 re = If[KolmogorovSmirnovTest[dis,NormalDistribution[], "ShortTestConclusion"] == 
"Do not reject", 1, 0];
 KSTL[[j]] = KSTL[[j]] + re;
 Remove[dis];
 Close[str];
 , {j, ic}, {k, r}]
```

part of the output.

```
i=2500 r=1 Memory= 75359488

KolmogorovSmirnovTest::ties: Ties exist in the data and will be     ignored for the KolmogorovSmirnov test, which assumes unique values.

i=2500 r=2 Memory= 118608248

KolmogorovSmirnovTest::ties: Ties exist in the data and will be ignored for the KolmogorovSmirnov test, which assumes unique values.

Remove::remal: Symbol Removed[dis] already removed.

i=2500 r=3 Memory= 118716136

Remove::remal: Symbol Removed[dis] already removed.

i=2500 r=4 Memory= 118738672

KolmogorovSmirnovTest::ties: Ties exist in the data and will be ignored for the KolmogorovSmirnov test, which assumes unique values.

General::stop: Further output of KolmogorovSmirnovTest::ties will be suppressed during this calculation.

Remove::remal: Symbol Removed[dis] already removed.

General::stop: Further output of Remove::remal will be suppressed during this calculation.

i=2500 r=5 Memory= 118762120

i=2500 r=6 Memory= 118784760

i=2500 r=7 Memory= 118806984

i=2500 r=8 Memory= 118829208

...

i=2500 r=44 Memory= 119643952

i=2500 r=45 Memory= 119666488

i=2500 r=46 Memory= 119689024

i=2500 r=47 Memory= 119711560
```

Be cause I have 50k files even the little difference fills all memory after some time.

Comment: Those errors are suggesting that the data is not in a numerical format. You will likely need to focus on getting the data into the program correctly. Try FullForm[dis] to see what you have.

Comment: The output of `FullForm[dis]` is  `List[0.704683, 0.230878,...,-0.641165, -0.028328]`. The errors mean that I have points that are equal in my list, and `KolmogorovSmirnovTest` will  ignored these.

Comment: Do you get an error in the first iteration? Try removing the Do loop (set ic=1) and see if the first iteration finishes without error.

Comment: @bills Yes, I get the same error. I don't think the memory issue is because of the errors. I can write `DeleteDuplicates[dis]` which solves the errors, but the memory problem is the same.

Comment: What is the memory issue? It looks to me as if the KS test disallows duplicate values -- hence removing them fixes that. Other than that, what is wrong with the memory? And of course, it is true that you have already removed the variable dis. Why not leave it in?

Comment: @bills you can see that at i=2500 r=8 Memory= 118829208` and `i=2500 r=47 Memory= 119711560` there is ~1000000 difference for ~40 iterations, after some time (I have 50000 files) this difference occupies most of my memory, and later crashes.